# React-Router-Dom v5 Throws 404 on first page load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I got this weird issue with React-Router-Dom.

If a user goes directly to route - other than Home "/" they get directly to the 404.html

If a user goes directly to Signup or Business Profile they get directed to the standard 404.html page

Only once they go to the home then they can visit the other routes

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" children={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/Signup" children={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="/NotFound" children={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/:businessProfileID" children={<BusinessProfile />} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use component prop, not children prop in the Route:

```
<Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
```

And the notFound page should not have a path, and should be the last route as it should act as a fallback.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route path="/:businessProfileID" component={BusinessProfile}
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

It was a hosting issue.

I'm using Firebase Hosting. When I first ran `firebase init` I didn't select the `single web page` option.

So all other routes weren't handled correctly

I ran firebase init again and it did the job